# Designing a file center in asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, dreamweaver

My university project is to design a file center ( it should be similar to 4shared.com) with `asp.net(c#)` and `SQL server`. Before I start to design I have some question, please help me.

1. Is it better to use `Dream weaver` or `visual studio` ? I am not familiar with `Dream weaver` but our teacher said it helps us. Whats your idea ? Learn `Dream weaver` or `visual studio` is enough ?
2. My site, according to users behaviour. should suggest to them , for example someone is trying to download `xx.mp3`, my site should suggest that other that downloaded `xx.mp3` also downloaded `yy.mp3` `ff.mp3` and so on. Now I don't know how should I save user behaviour. Should I keep this information in my database tables or elsewhere? Please tell me how to implement this.
3. Another question is about my tables. what are your ideas about my site tables? What important column  should they have? And of course how should I save files? Is it better to save them in database or only save their path on tables and save them in site folder?
4. Last question - I am not professional in `asp.net` and `c#`. Will it be possible for me to design this website or should I tell my teacher that I cant do this ?

Please, if you have any tutorial about designing a file center or about my question put it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll follow Ruben's formula: Your question is subjective to personal opinions. Here is mine:

1. Go on with Visual Studio, it can edit web pages very well, so you don't really need Dream Weaver, also it will help you in writing code and testing your application. Dream weaver may help do somethings like creating menus and stuff... I say you should learn to those things without dream weaver, still it is up to you.
2. User behaviour is not vital. Of course you can always choose to track user's activity for the convenience of suggestions, yet this feature will take a while to implement, and if we count that a good chunk of user will prefer to turn that off I say you should not put priority on this part of the project (unless, your project is exactly about that).
3. If in doubt, always have an `Id`. The columns Rubens suggests are good for auditory so consider that too. I want to tell you that security is paramount. All the cycle from login to logout, change password and such seems simple, but requires special attention. I will self-promote here a bit, start by [My answer to Recover / Reset lost password options via email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330223/402022).
4. You can do it, really. The question is how long will it take (will it be done in time?), I mean... there is some learning involved as in anything. There two things you must know:

   - It is absurd to pretend you know the future. In software development, if you have done something in the past, chances are you can just reuse the code... if you definitively can't reuse your old code, it is because: a) you haven't done it or b) you haven't done it well enough. So, every time you are in front to a project there will be things that you haven't done, those will be the parts that take more time (because for the other, you just reuse) and it is ridiculously hard to tell how long will they take. So, No. I can't tell you if you are gonna do it in time, and also it is that way all the time and we get things done regardless.
   - You can always be mediocre... Bad advice? yes, a bit. But in truth, if you have to present something, anything, for a deadline... and you don't know what to do, you can always go with what you already know. This way you will pass easier, and also, you will get used to not push yourself (ergo, be mediocre). So, decide, what matters to you: Getting good grades*, or learning new things? [Yes, you can do both].

*: That is only a dichotomy if we assume bad teachers, good teachers will not give good grade to a project well done that tries nothing new, instead will incentive a project that is innovative but barely works (or that's the theory).

Remember to take a look at the antecedents, yes 4Shared, but also Google Drive, Microsoft SkyDrive, Dropbox, Mega...

Is your site, one where people do backup of personal media, or is it one where people share files with others? Will everybody be able to access uploaded files? Does it make sense to avoid duplicate files? Does it make sense to cipher the files (With a personal key?)? Do not answer me, just consider them.

Lasly, Tutorials? No, sorry. Still, you can researchs the parts, such as: access control, file upload, redirections, session management and so forth. Do don't really need a tutorial, take that idea out of your system, it is stopping you from being the one who does things for which there is no tutorial (and maybe write one?).

Anyway, I want to suggest to you to have a read of [Post/Redirect/Get at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) And also in [this very website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381162/post-redirect-get-with-asp-net). And I also want to suggest you to not hesitate to ask questions (ah, yes, search first, stand in the shoulders of giants).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is subjective to personal opinions. Here is mine:

1. I would recommend Visual Studio for working with C# and ASP.NET.
2. Yes, you should keep the user behavior in database. You can track the user behavior with the user session, and saving each download related to the user session.
3. Any database tables should have an `Id`, `CreationDate`, `CreatedBy`, `LastModificationDate` and `LastModifiedBy`.
4. You should try and retry before telling yourself you can do something. If you are in university, you should learn to overcome obstacle and challenges.